# Two column layout, different height images

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a layout with two columns. On the left side is one image, and on the right side the image should be half the height of the image on the left but still take up the full width of the screen. I cant seem to make the image on the right side 50% of the height of the one on the left. The margin on the top is to clear space for a fixed header.

```css
.col {
  margin-top: 80px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
}

.row-l {
  width: 60%;
}

.row-r {
  width: 39.5%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <img class="row-l" src="cover.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;">
  <img class="row-r" src="phone.jpg" style="max-width: 100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: `50% of the height of the one on the left` there is no relation between both image, so using `height:50%` doesn't meant 50% of the other image. % is related to parent element

Comment: The parent elements height is the height of the first image since I did not give it a fixed height.

Comment: you see this, without image i cannot see this :) ... and it's the size of the first image only if the first image is bigger ... and if there is no height specified the % won't work as the height is auto and auto means the height of it's content and thus the bigger image ;)

Comment: I edited in a picture.

Comment: no, we need the picture in the code and not a screenshot

Comment: I don't know how to add the images like that.

Comment: host them somewhere and use full path ? your site is locally built ?

Comment: Yes, just practicing. I'm trying to copy this, this is where I got the two images. https://thenextweb.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I advice you to go with a flex layout and use the images as a background like this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.col {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  height: 40vh;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.row-l {
  width:60%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url("https://lorempixel.com/400/400/");
}

.row-r {
  width:40%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-image:url("https://lorempixel.com/400/500/");
  height:50%;
  margin-top:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="col">
  <div class="row-l" ></div>
  <div class="row-r"></div>
</div>
```